# Upgrading process interrupted (from Ubuntu 12 to 14)

Tags: upgrade

I was upgrading Ubuntu 12.04 to 14, and in the middle of the process, the power went off. Now my laptop doesn’t start and I have very important information that I need on the hard drive. This is the current status of the laptop and the things I’ve done trying to fix it:

I turn on the laptop and it gives me five options:
Ubuntu, with linux 3.8 generic.
Ubuntu, with linux 3.8 generic (recovery mode).
Previous Linux versions.
Memory test (memtest86+).
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200).

From the above list, and based on the forums, I’ve tried the second option (Ubuntu…(recovery  mode)). Once there, I’ve tried:

1. Resume  Resume normal boot (Filesystem check or mount failed. A maintance shell will now be started. CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re-trying filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored).
2. dpkg        repair broken packages (after selecting OK, says: 
   /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 76: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
   Fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
   /dev/sda1: clean, 554919/9609216 files, 23666655/38419712 blocks)
3. grub        Upgdate grub bootloader (doesn’t work, neither  sudo apt-get update nor sudo apt-get upgrade)
4. Network     Enable networking (same outcome than in dpkg)

I also tried booting from a CD but doesn’t work either. The ubuntu installer I’ve is for Windows.

When I checked the general status, this is the report I receive:

General information
System mode: read only
CPU information: 2x1600MHz
Network connectivity: none

Detailed disk usage
Filesystem             Size, Used, Avail, Use (the previous 4 items match with my hard drive usage)    Mounted on /dev/sda1

Software RAID state
No software RAID detected (mdstat)

LVM state
No LVM detected (vgscan)

System database (APT)
Database is consistent: unknown (read-only filesystem)

I'm not very knowledgable on this matter.
Thank you in advance to whoever can help me with this.

Cheers.

Oscar.

Comment: same here, managed to fix this?